# how capture a moving customcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, custom-controls

I try to explain my problem:

I got many customcontrols of same type on a panel.

At runtime I'm free to move any custumcontrol ( mousedown  and mousemove events) in the form with mouse over any others customcontrols using bringtofront() to have it over all.

Now I need to know when the control I'm moving is over any other control and  which control is under.

So far I've tryed to use drag-n-drop events but without success, there's some other way to do this or I've to re elaborate it with drag events?

thank you all for help

and sorry for my English.

EDIT:

The controls are cards game and my final goal is to use cards to create logical sequence following rules based on card value and/or color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve the problem with drag-and-drop because you're not actually *dropping* one control onto the other control. You're merely moving them around in the form.

You need to become familiar with **Z order**, which is the front-to-back arrangement of objects in a virtual 3D space. To adjust the Z order, you can call the [`BringToFront`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) and [`SendToBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback.aspx) methods of any object that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

The Z order is also exposed by the *parent* (container) control's [`Controls` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx). Using the [`GetChildIndex` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh.aspx), you can determine the position of any control within the Z order.

So now, all you need to do is figure out which control the control you're dragging is over. Do that by comparing the [`Location` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) of the two controls. When you know that the locations of two controls overlap, check their respective Z order indices to see which one is on top.

Comment: @Cody: I use get and set childindex methods for zorder very well. but the problem to figure out which control is under the control i'm moving the problem. Maybe I've to store position for each control in an array and compare cursor position to figure out which control is under? Sure but there's no best solution at all?

Comment: @Christian: You can just loop through the controls and compare their current positions. There's no reason to cache the values in an array; the way I understand your design, they're subject to be constantly changing. You need to access them dynamically. But no, there's no particularly *elegant* solution for this. It's extremely unusual to float controls around like that in an application.

Comment: @Cody: Application is a cardgame.... usually cards (controls) are moved aroud de board.. :-)

Comment: @Christian: That would have been a good thing to include in your question. It gives people context of what you're trying to do. Indeed, it makes a lot more sense to me that way. :-) I bet there's someone here who has made a card game in .NET and could tell you exactly what they did! (That person isn't me, though, unfortunately.)

Comment: Dont' forget, it's not just location in x,y space. You have to factor their dimensions as well. Just because the upper left corner of the control on top is not at the same location as the upper left corner of the control bellow, doesn't mean that the controls are not overlapping. The control with higher z-index maybe much smaller than the one bellow....

Comment: @bleepzter: Yup. [`Rectangle.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kh3ee9e.aspx) is the easy test for that.

Comment: @Christian: By the way, you do know that you can edit your existing question to include additional information, right? Just use the "edit" link at the bottom left, just underneath the tags!